# How to detect when Crashlytics has NOT created a report

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have two code paths that needs to execute on app launch:
1. When Crashlytics detects a report from the last run
2. When it is a clean launch, ie, no crash report was detected.

Crashlytics provides (and recommends) that this method be used to detect crashes:

```
- (void) crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report
```

but the documentation specifically says that the method is not called synchronously during initialization.  So while I can use this for detecting case #1, I don't think it is possible to use the same method to detect case #2 without possibly introducing a race condition.

As far as I can tell, the current framework does not expose any method to check for the existence of a report, either in Crashlytics.h or CLSReport.h.  If it did, I could check for the existence of a crash report before the framework initializes.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed by Mike (from Fabric)

Mike -- I'm used to assuming that delegate methods and callbacks cannot be assumed to happen synchronously, or on the same thread.  You seem to be saying that I can/should make that assumption here, so that this (psdeudocode) would work:

(in AppDelegate)

```
- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {

     self.HadCrash = YES;
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        completionHandler(YES);
    }];
}
```

(In AppDelegate didFinishLaunching)

```
crashlytics.delegate = self;
[crashlytics init];   // presumably if the delegate method IS going to be called, it will be called here.
if (!HadCrash) 
{ // do "no crash" stuff here }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here, there are two methods that can be used to know about a crash that happened.

1) `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report;`

This method has the following restrictions:

- It is not called synchronously during initialization
- It does not give you the ability to prevent the report from being submitted
- The report object itself is immutable

The most important benefits are that the ability to report crashes is not affected in any way.

2) `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL submit))completionHandler;`

- This is called synchronously when the last execution of the app ended in a crash.
- You can then take whatever action you want to take, but the report will not be sent unless the `completionHandler` is called with `YES` passed in. If `NO` is passed in then the call will be finished, but no report would be sent.

Here's a sample implementation from the docs:

```
- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    // Use this opportunity to take synchronous action on a crash. See Crashlytics.h for
    // details and implications.

    // Maybe consult NSUserDefaults or show a UI prompt.

    // But, make ABSOLUTELY SURE you invoke completionHandler, as the SDK
    // will not submit the report until you do. You can do this from any
    // thread, but that's optional. If you want, you can just call the
    // completionHandler and return.
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        completionHandler(YES);
    }];
}
```

I think that addresses the question, but let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Mike, you have answered a different question than the one asked.  I am specifically trying to determine when a crash report is NOT present on launch of the app, not when it is present.

Comment: Right, so you would need to wrap the check for a crash, if CrashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution isn't called, then there's no crash, but you could still take action on it before the rest of the init?

Comment: How do you propose I detect if the delegate method is NOT called?  Set the delegate, perform the framework initialization, and....?  I could set up a timer, but that potentially leads to the race condition I mentioned in the OP

Comment: Setup the delegate and a boolean flag HadCrash false (for example). Within crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution, set HadCrash to true ; return the handler, then based on the value of HadCrash decide what to do.

Comment: I just don't see the race condition. You set the boolean flag, head into the delegate code, and do not other action then change a boolean and return the handler. All of this would be completed within milliseconds. I think a race condition potential there is extremely limited.

Comment: Correct, since crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution is synchronous, it would provide a very limited blocking call. My understanding is that the time for a race condition to develop would be extremely small.

Comment: I wanted to post some pseudo-code but the comment/reply system doesn't let you format.  I've posted your proposed solution below.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it.

Comment: I still think that an exposed method to check if a crash report was created on the previous run is a better solution, but I'll take what I can get.  Thank you for your help

Comment: I'll share the feedback with the team. Thanks for working through it with me.

Comment: I'm just paranoid about multithreading issues, and have forgotten how to code simpler cases  :)